# Create border for overlay element as child of parent with dynamic width and height

Tags: html, css

I would like to render a border **over** an image on mouseover, but accomplish it solely with CSS.

My structure is very simple:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <img />
</div>
```

The idea is that `.overlay` gets a 5px border and becomes visible when the mouse hovers over `.outer`

The image can be of any width / height - it is not known and cannot be specified exclusively.

The only problem is that due to box-model laws i end up with the right and bottom border being rendered outside of `.outer` because `100% width / height` on `.overlay` already cover the full width of `outer`.

In order to fully understand what i am trying to explain, [please refer to my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EgY8G/).

How can i make `.overlay` be exactly as wide and high as required in order to display the border fully above my image? I am looking for a cross-browser compatible solution, so modifying box-model behaviour for the problematic element does not appear to be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to overlaying `divs`, just use the pseudo element `:after`. It works for dynamic content and only requires a parent element.

Basically, just set the parent `div` to `display:inline-block` to be the same size as the child. Then set the `:after` content to `width:100%`/`height:100%` - thus taking the size of any dynamic image. The HTML is simple, as it only requires a single parent `div`, no need for an extra `overlay` class.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/t3BuS/)

**HTML** - extremely simple - no redundancy.

```
<div>
    <img src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2704840564/ace6835dc7c12861b013a8f1ac3b1041.png">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    vertical-align: top;
}

div:hover:after {
    content: "\A";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid black;
    opacity: 0.75;
    background: red;
    z-index: 2;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Splendid! Works like a charm as it seems! Thanks!

Comment: I like it, but i fear it may be problematic because of the box-sizing stuff. Its what i meant when saying i didn't want to modify box-model behaviour. I mean, generally i am not entirely closed up to using this solution but.. i don't know, it feels "unsafe". What's your take on this?

Comment: @CummanderCheckov It's completely safe. No drawbacks at all. In fact, this is the most common method of achieving such a thing. But, if you don't like it, that's fine.

Comment: @CummanderCheckov Here is the support on box sizing. http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing .. If it isn't supported, it isn't a noticeable issue anyways. It works on **all** major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `width:100%;` and `height:100%`, set the `right` and `bottom` positions to `0px`.

http://jsfiddle.net/hTECe/3/

Note that by default there will be a small margin below the image. This can be solved by any one of these solutions:

- Set the image to `display:block`. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image))
- Set the `vertical-align` of the image to `top`, `middle`, or `bottom`
- Set the `line-height` of the outer frame to `0`

CSS

```
.outer img
{
   display:block;
}

.outer:hover .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I came across this thing as well, as i use the same procedures for creating a full page overlay. But i don't know either why images seem to create a bottom margin or padding by default? Where does this come from?

Comment: @Cummander Checkox - see my edit and the new jsFiddle. The problem was that there was already invisible padding inside the outer frame.

Comment: Yes, but that shouldn't be the case, right? I wonder, how can one get rid of that padding altogether?

Comment: @Cummander Checkov - I've figured out how to get rid of the padding. See the updated answer